# ansible for LDAP server,give syntax error for "slap_dmodules_path"

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create ansible playbook, that create LDAP server.
This is my code:

```
---
- hosts: ldapserver
  become: true
  become_user: root
  roles:
  - slapd-config
    slap_dmodules_path: /usr/lib/ldap
    slapd_olc_rootdn_password: {{'PWfromCLI'}}
    slapd_mdb_rootdn_password: {{'PWfromCLI'}}
    slapd_monitor_rootdn_password: {{'PWfromCLI'}}
    slapd_additional_modules: [ 'memberof' ]
    slapd_mdb_config:
      olcSuffix: "dc=example,dc=com"
    slapd_mdb_overlays:
      memberof:
        olcOverlay: memberof
        objectClass: olcMemberOf
        olcMemberOfDangling: ignore
```

I get the following error:

```
The error appears to have been in '/playbook.yml': line 7, column 23, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  - slapd-config
    slap_dmodules_path: /usr/lib/ldap
                      ^ here
```

I don't understand what is the problem, and how to fix it. Can you help? <3 jennifer

Answer (score 0):

- slapd-config
  slap_dmodules_path: /usr/lib/ldap
                    ^ here

it seems like this should be slapd_modules  i think you had it misspelled or there is a problem with the spaces